# Gluon Mobile Not Being Able to Port to iOS

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm on the home stretch of this App I'm working on and I can't seem to get it to port to iOS. When trying to build my application on iOS, I get an OutOfMemory exception over and over again.

Then I tried to build a basic Gluon Mobile application and port it to iOS and I get this:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:createDefaultIOSLauncher UP-TO-DATE
:compileIosJava UP-TO-DATE
:processIosResources UP-TO-DATE
:iosClasses UP-TO-DATE
:iosExtractNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
:createIpa
RoboVM has detected that you are running on a slow HDD. Please consider mounting a RAM disk.
To create a 2GB RAM disk, run this in your terminal:
SIZE=2048 ; diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RoboVM RAM Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((SIZE * 2048))`
See http://docs.robovm.com/ for more info
RoboVM has detected that you are running on a slow HDD. Please consider mounting a RAM disk.
To create a 2GB RAM disk, run this in your terminal:
SIZE=2048 ; diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RoboVM RAM Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((SIZE * 2048))`
See http://docs.robovm.com/ for more info
Root pattern javax.annotations.**.* matches no classes
Root pattern javax.inject.**.* matches no classes
RoboVM has detected that you are running on a slow HDD. Please consider mounting a RAM disk.
To create a 2GB RAM disk, run this in your terminal:
SIZE=2048 ; diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RoboVM RAM Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((SIZE * 2048))`
See http://docs.robovm.com/ for more info
Root pattern javax.annotations.**.* matches no classes
Root pattern javax.inject.**.* matches no classes
Warning: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement is a phantom class!
Warning: java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption is a phantom class!
Warning: java.nio.file.FileSystem is a phantom class!
Warning: java.nio.file.OpenOption is a phantom class!
Warning: java.nio.file.FileSystems is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.TimedEvent is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.EventToken is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.ValueDefinition is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.EventDefinition is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.Producer is a phantom class!
Warning: com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.FlightRecorder is a phantom class!
Daemon stopping because JVM tenured space is exhausted
Daemon stopping because JVM tenured space is exhausted
```

My IMac is running **8GB of RAM on a 2.7GHz I5.**

I have also attempted mounting a RoboVM RAM Disk to no success. Please help!

Comment: Try to add this JVM option: `-Xmx2048m`. You can add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m` to the `gradle.properties` file, or set the value in your IDE preferences.

Comment: Thank you José. This seems promising. I will mark an answer as to what I did exactly if my current operation completes! Or you can just do it so you can get the credit when I mark the answer as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the iOS deployment requires a lot of memory, and it is a good practice to increase by default the maximum allocation memory pool of the JVM heap, up until 2 GB.

Running from your IDE, you can set this default value in the Gradle preferences.

For instance, on NetBeans, go to Preferences->Miscellaneous->Gradle, Scripts & Tasks, and as Gradle JVM arguments add `-Xmx2048m`:

[image: Gradle Arguments]

Another option is to set a gradle property in your `gradle.properties` file (the one with the ANDROID_HOME property, under `<user>/.gradle`):

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
```

This property file will be applied either running from IDE or from command line, so it is more appropriate.

A typical situation where an out of memory error is found is the first time the RoboVM compiler is launched. Luckily, all the compiled classes are cached, so restarting the task just resumes the process.

Also, if the process fails, sometimes can be convenient to stop all the deamon threads with `gradle --stop` and `./gradlew --stop`, and start the task again.

If the process ends successfully, even if there are warning messages, just check on your iOS device that the app was installed and runs fine. Note that you could find memory issues as well, but this is a different issue.

*Edit*

when running long tasks, it's always convenient using `--info` to find out more about the process, with a more verbose output.

Also, the process can be run from the console (from NetBeans, right click on the build.gradle file and select Tools->Open in Terminal).

Comment: Can I ignore any "Daemon stopping because JVM tenured space is exhausted" messages or is that a sign that I should restart the porting operation and let it continue from the latest point stored in cache?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Does your task end successfully?

Comment: I stupidly closed my Netbeans in the middle of it with the Daemon thread message. Now the projects fail to load in Netbeans. Will restart my computer now, and attempt again.

Comment: Ok, but in case you still have the same issue, run `clean`, or even remove the `build`, `.nb-gradle` and `.gradle` folders of the project, and try again.

Comment: I keep getting to this GregorianCalendar class message and then the Daemon thread errors occur: "Warning: sun.util.calendar.LocalGregorianCalendar is a phantom class!"

Comment: Phantom classes are referred to by other classes, but cannot be loaded. This is not an issue (unless you really need them!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142747/discussion-between-a-sharma-and-jose-pereda).